# How to change width and height of graphic 'rect' programmatically in Echarts (by implementing onClick event or make it resizable by dragging)

Tags: javascript, html, css, echarts

I'm using latest echarts and trying to put a rectangle on the canvas using [graphic](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#graphic) option.
We can set width and height of *`type: 'rect'`* by using Shape.width and Shape.height according to [this](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#graphic.elements-rect.shape.width) documentation.

What I want to do is that I want to change that width and height of rectangle

1. by clicking on it (by implementing [onClick](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#graphic.elements-rect.onclick) event)
2. by dragging like in css 'resize' property to a div. Is this possible in echarts?

Here is the sample option code that I'm currently trying to implement. You can use it by replacing it [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-stack). The setter function `setWidth()` can change the value of width variable but `Shape.width` will not call `getWidth()` function again. There will not be a new render happening.

```
let width = 100;

function getWidth() {
  return width;
}

function setWidth(value) {
  width = value;
}

option = {
  graphic: {
    elements: [
      {
        type: 'rect',
        draggable: true,
        shape: {
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: getWidth(),
          height: 100
        },
        style: {
          fill: 'red'
        },
        onclick: function(e) {
          setWidth(400)
        }
      }
    ],
    grid: {
      left: '3%',
      right: '4%',
      bottom: '3%',
      containLabel: true
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Echarts options are usually not dynamic. Which means that if you change any option, you'll have to call `yourChartName.setOption(option)` ([doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption)).

```js
function setWidth(value) {
  option.graphic.elements[0].shape.width=value;
  myChart.setOption(option);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it! 
Do you have any idea about Question 2? How to resize the rectangle by dragging its edge like we do to textarea element. Is it possible to make it resizable with mouse dragging action.

Comment: You should be able to do it with workarounds but i don't know exactly how.

Comment: Did you ever solve this point 2 ?